# Gatsbyjs .env.production variables not available in browser

Tags: nginx, environment-variables, gatsby

I am trying to deploy my Gatsbyjs site, but when I load the page, I see an error telling me that an environment variable is missing.

Details:

- I'm serving the contents of the built /public directory via NGINX.
- Everything works in development.
- I have a .env.production file with my environment variables.
- I have `require("dotenv").config({ path: '.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}d', })` in my gatsby-config.js file.
- I have tried prefixing my env vars with `GATSBY_` which it seems to make no difference.
- I have read every bit of documentation and every SO solution I could find. Nothing seems to make any difference.

I've been stuck on this for too long. I have a deadline coming up shortly and I need this to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a typo in your `require("dotenv").config({ path: '.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}d', }) `( the "d") or it's just in the question?

Comment: Do you have any custom commands for building/developing in your `package.json`?

Comment: @FerranBuireu no, it's just a typo in the question. I didn't have any custom build commands. Turns out it had to do with the way I was uploading the files to my server that prevented me from seeing the effects of adding GATSBY_ to my vars.

Comment: @FerranBuireu Thanks for giving it a look! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might run into a similar issue in the future, I would recommend double checking the files on your server and make sure that their hashes match the output of the build process. I finally realized that there was a discrepancy between the two, caused by a bug in the deployment process.

If you haven't already, double check the docks. I'm no Gatsby expert, but what seems to have made the difference for me was prefixing my env vars with `GATSBY_`.